# Python unittest, results vary depending on print statement

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm mildly confused. I'm testing a django application with python's unittest library. All of a sudden, after running my tests with 100 % success for some minutes, suddenly an error appears. Ok I thought, I must have just added some stupid syntax error. I started looking at the test and then my code, I then tried to print out the results which are being compared with assertEqual before they are compared. Suddenly if I do that, the test runs!!! :o

Why is this? has anyone experienced this before. I swear, the only change I made was adding a print statement inside my test function. I'll post this function before and after

Before (Fails)

```
def test_swap_conditionals(self):
    """
    Test conditional template keys
    """
    testStr = "My email is: {?email}"
    swapStr = self.t.swap(testStr)
    # With email
    self.assertEqual(swapStr, "My email is: john@baconfactory.com")

    # Without email
    self.t.template_values = {"phone" : "00458493"}
    swapStr = self.t.swap(testStr)
    self.assertEqual(swapStr, "My email is: ")
```

After (Success)

```
def test_swap_conditionals(self):
    """
    Test conditional template keys
    """
    testStr = "My email is: {?email}"
    swapStr = self.t.swap(testStr)
    print(swapStr) #diff here
    # With email
    self.assertEqual(swapStr, "My email is: john@baconfactory.com")

    # Without email
    self.t.template_values = {"phone" : "00458493"}
    swapStr = self.t.swap(testStr)
    self.assertEqual(swapStr, "My email is: ")
```

Comment: @RickyA correct, this was my fault when copying this in here. The snippets are exactly the same except in the second one I print out swapStr and for some reason this makes the test run

Comment: ok, i formatted and added a comment on that line

Comment: what happens when you remove the print again now? and on what assert does it fails?

Comment: With the print removed it fails unless I comment out the part #Without email. So it's failing on this assertion: self.assertEqual(swapStr, "My email is: "). self.t.template_values contains a dictionary with values that are suppose to be swapped out if they are present, the {?email} means, check if email is a valid key, if it's not present then return "", that's why I'm expecting to get "My email is: " when I overwrite self.t.template_values to contain only the key phone.

Comment: can it be self.t still contains the email after the second call to self.t.swap? print(self.t) after each swap and print(swapStr) after each assignment.

Comment: I think you're correct. It definitely has something to do with self.t still containing these values. I tried seperating the two tests, that is I added the second case to it's own function and now it runs. But this is very weird behaviour, and the fact that a print has some effect is very strange. I have a setUp function where self.t is initialised with the dictionary containing {email, phone}. So that might be it, even though I overwrite it, it just goes on setting it up before each assert? My believe was that it runs setUp before every function, but not before every assertion

Comment: ahh, actually it does not run everytime. It ran 2 times then it failed 2 times and then it ran again :/

Comment: can you try this: `self.assertEqual(str(swapStr), "My email is: john@baconfactory.com")`. Maybe the print 'force' the string evaluation (ie swap is "lazy" or a kind of proxy

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is some external reason.

What you can check:

- Rerun the test several times under the same conditions. Is it always failing or passing? Or is it a 'flipper' test? This might be caused by timing issues (although unlikely).
- Put the test in its own class, so there are no side effects from other unit tests.
- If the test in its own test class was passing the reason is a side effect by:

  - other unit tests
  - startup/teardown functionality

Comment: Ok so I put both tests in their own isolated functions, they are not depending on anything from setUp, they create their own instance of the Template class, fill in the dictionary themselves and then swap out the values. This works, I've tried running the tests couple of times and they always return success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well embarrassing, but this was completely my fault. The swap function was looking up every conditional template variable on the line and then iterating over that list one conditional template variable at a time, so either it missed keys it already had or it got lucky and it happened to hit that key.

Example

```
line: "This is my {?email}, and this is my {?phone}"

finds:
[{?email}, {?phone}]

iterates over [{?email}, {?phone}]
1. {?email}
key being compared = phone : '00549684'
```

It has phone as a key but it completely disregards it and does not swap it out because
it's just holding {?email} so it simply returns "".

I'm sincerely sorry to waste all your time here. Thanks for good answers. I am refactoring the code now for the better, and definitely taking a coffee break :D